# vbsript and excel delete all worksheets except last one

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to delete all worksheet in excel exept last one and save it then move its location. I can not get it took work as it deletes all other worksheets but errors out with and out of range error.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\M-tek 10-31-12_Tony.xlsx")
i = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Do while i = i
i = i - 1
objWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
Loop
```

Comment: `Do while i = i` is a nice infinite loop. I think you should re-visit your loop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will be infinite since your condition can never be false (`i` will *always* equal `i`). So you need to change your loop to start at the last-but-one worksheet and work its way backwards to the first. You're nearly there.

```
count = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1

For i = count To 1 Step -1
    objWorkbook.Worksheets{i}.Delete
Next
```

That should do it (in fact it does, I just tested it).

Comment: That would great  mate. Thanks i been failing short on this one. I will have to read up on the step command